# Asking about using the Google cloud with Windows Phones

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I wanted to check here, to see if the question would be appropriate, before asking:

> How can I make use of the Google cloud with a Windows phone?

This would definitely be the site the question would fit on, but I'm afraid it might be a bit too far-reaching in scope for an SE question.

For more detail: I'm looking at (finally) upgrading into a smartphone and, the more I consider my options, I'm really leaning towards a Windows phone. However, all my cloud-based services (mail, calendar, data storage, instant messaging) are in Google's space - and I'd like to keep them there. I want to know how feasible this would be with built-in features & apps of the Windows Phone OS, and/or what tools I'd need to make it happen.

Would this query be appropriate for the site, or is it something more suited (as far as the SE world goes) for chat? If not suitable for the site, is your chat room generally active enough to support this?

EDIT: Currently, there's nobody else in the chat room, the last post was 23 days ago, and breaks in conversation generally last for weeks. So, I'm guessing chat's a no-go.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that it would be okay if you were specific about which services you need to use and an existing question does not exist.